# pandas - add missing rows on the basis of column values to have linspace

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, autofill, linear-interpolation

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
     a   b  c
0  0.5  10  7
1  1.0   6  6
2  2.0   1  7
3  2.5   6 -5
4  3.5   9  7
```

and I would like to fill the missing columns with respect to the column 'a' on the basis of a certain step. In this case, given the step of 0.5, I would like to fill the 'a' column with the missing values, that is 1.5 and 3.0, and set the other columns to null, in order to obtain the following result.

```
     a     b    c
0  0.5  10.0  7.0
1  1.0   6.0  6.0
2  1.5   NaN  NaN
3  2.0   1.0  7.0
4  2.5   6.0 -5.0
5  3.0   NaN  NaN
6  3.5   9.0  7.0
```

Which is the cleanest way to do this with pandas or other libraries like numpy or scipy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create array by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), then create `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
step= .5
idx = np.arange(df['a'].min(), df['a'].max() + step, step)
df = df.set_index('a').reindex(idx).reset_index()
print (df)
     a     b    c
0  0.5  10.0  7.0
1  1.0   6.0  6.0
2  1.5   NaN  NaN
3  2.0   1.0  7.0
4  2.5   6.0 -5.0
5  3.0   NaN  NaN
6  3.5   9.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 5):

One simple way to achieve that is to first create the index you want and then merge the remaining of the information on it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.5, 1, 2, 2.5, 3.5],
                   'b': [10, 6, 1, 6, 9],
                   'c': [7, 6, 7, -5, 7]})
ls = np.arange(df.a.min(), df.a.max(), 0.5)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':ls})
new_df = new_df.merge(df, on='a', how='left')
```